# VBA Searching for emails containing a substring within the body

Tags: vba, outlook, filtering, wildcard

Contrary to tutorials like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison), the % wildcard character does not seem to do what it's supposed to for me. Much like a normal search on Outlook itself, it only returns instances where the phrase is a standalone word. Ex: If I searched for 'cat' in an email body it wouldn't return an email containing 'bobcats'

Here is the code I wrote, the bolded line is where the % is used in the string filter. In the actual Outlook folder I plan on filtering, there is one email where the ID phrase 'WR2065416' is present in the body. Searching for the entire phrase 'WR2065416' in my code does indeed find the email (with and without the %'s) but searching only for '2065416' returns nothing (again with and without the %'s). From what I tried out myself, it seems the potential issue is that the email body isn't treated the same in this filter as the email subject, as changing 'textdescription' to 'subject' made the %'s start working to find any desired substrings.

```
Sub OutlookKeywordSearch()

    ' Declarations
    
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim nSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mail As Object
    Dim topPublicFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myFolderItems
    Dim filtItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim results As Integer
    Dim phrase As Variant
    
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set nSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set topPublicFolder = nSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
    Set myFolder = topPublicFolder.Folders("ParentDirectory1").Folders("ParentDirectory2").Folders("ExampleFolder1")
    Set myFolderItems = myFolder.Items
    results = 0
    
    ' Phrase to search: 2065416
 
    ' Search in ExampleFolder1 for Given Phrase
        
**    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%2065416%'"**
        
    Set filtItems = myFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    If filtItems.Count > 0 Then
        results = filtItems.Count
    End If
                
    MsgBox ("Found " + CStr(results) + " instances in ExampleFolder1 of this phrase!")
    results = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: In Trust Center -> Email Security -> Script in Folders there are checkboxes for *Allow script in shared folders* and *Allow script in Public Folders*. There **may** be an impact.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to run the following code in my Outlook to check how that works:

```
Sub SearchMacro()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strSearchFolderName As String
    
    strSearchFolderName = "Search Macro"
    
    'Delete "Search Macro" Search Folder from a previous search
    Dim oSearchFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set oSearchFolders = Outlook.Session.DefaultStore.GetSearchFolders
    
    For Each oFolder In oSearchFolders
        If oFolder.Name = strSearchFolderName Then
            oFolder.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'Prompt for Search Query
    strSearch = InputBox("Enter your search query: ", "Search Macro")

    'Search within the Subject and Message Body
    Dim strDASLFilter As String
    strDASLFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" & strSearch & "%'"

    'Set search scope to the Inbox and Sent Items (will include subfolders)
    Dim strScope As String
    strScope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items'"

    'Perform the search
    Dim objSearch As Search
    Set objSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strDASLFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder")

    'Save the search results to a Search Folder
    objSearch.Save (strSearchFolderName)
    
    'Add the Description and display the Search Folder in the current Outlook window
    Set oSearchFolders = Outlook.Session.DefaultStore.GetSearchFolders
    For Each oFolder In oSearchFolders
        If oFolder.Name = strSearchFolderName Then
            oFolder.Description = "You searched for: " & strSearch
            Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = oFolder
        End If
    Next

    Set objSearch = Nothing
    Set oSearchFolders = Nothing
    Exit Sub

'Error handling
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error: " & Err & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Error(Err)

End Sub
```

And I can confirm that partial words were found correctly. For example, to find all emails with `account` strings and more I entered the `ccoun` string got the correct results in the corresponding search folder.

Comment: I found it to be working in my main inbox yet not in public folders, could this be tested?

Answer (score 0):

`ci_phrasematch` an alternative to `Like` is demonstrated in [Search for a phrase in the body of items in a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder).

```vb
Sub Search_Inbox()

    Dim objFolder As Folder
    
    Dim filteredItems As Items
    
    Dim strFilter As String
        
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Default Inbox
    Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder
    If (Session.defaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled) Then
    
        ' compare this sample filter to your filter for supNumber
        strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
          & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) _
          & " ci_phrasematch '2065416'"
        'Debug.Print strFilter
        
        'restrict items
        Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
        'Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.count & " nbox items."
        
        If filteredItems.count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To filteredItems.count
                Debug.Print filteredItems(i).Subject
                Debug.Print filteredItems(i).ReceivedTime
                ' filteredItems(i).Display
            Next
            
        End If
        
        MsgBox "Completed!"
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using ci_phrasematch as illustrated here, didn't work in finding the email with just '2065416', inputting 'WR2065416' does return with one result though. Works the same as like from the looks of it.

Comment: I cannot test public folders. Consider testing in your inbox and clarifying in the question post whether `Like` and `ci_phrasematch` succeeded or failed there.

Comment: I set up a separate search for my Main Inbox with the same criteria, searching for a part of a phrase within the body. It worked with like and I'm assuming ci_phrasematch as well. Seems to be an issue with public folders or the way I am searching through the public folders?

Comment: Without access to public folders I cannot comment but now that you have confirmed the code works on inbox you could ask a new question, unpolluted with invalid answers, specifying inbox working and public folder not working. There could be others with that information or access to public folders to check your results.